# Android showing PDF using google viewer

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to show the PDF in WEB view using Google viewer from below code

```
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfUrl);
```

but some time I am getting problem showing error **"You have reached the Bandwidth limit for...."**  see below error image

Why I am getting this error, pleases suggest me any solution

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned it as you are getting this problem some times, Answer to your question is available at [google support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en) , do refer for more details .

In Short ,

Certain activities that transfer large amounts of data in a short period of time can cause an account to reach the bandwidth limit.( May be while reading a larger size pdf ) .